# Getting WARNING [liquibase.resource] Cannot create filesystem for url file: <classpath jar> while liquibase update

Tags: java, amazon-ec2, liquibase, snowflake-schema, amazon-linux-2

I am trying to run liquibase for snowflake with liquibase jar

Version : 4.4.1

Getting error for my classpath jar file

```
[2022-03-23 11:50:57] WARNING [liquibase.resource] Cannot create filesystem for url file:./liquibase-snowflake-4.4.1.jar
```

And Error :

```
Caused by: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: SQL compilation error:
```

Object 'DB.PUBLIC.DATABASECHANGELOG' does not exist or not authorized.

Command I am using :

```
java \
    -jar liquibase.jar \
        --username='user' \
        --password='pass' \
        --driver='net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver' \
        --classpath=./liquibase-snowflake-4.4.1.jar:./snowflake-jdbc-3.9.2.jar \
        --changeLogFile='./changelog.xml' \
        --defaultSchemaName=PUBLIC \
        --logLevel='info' \
        --url='myurl' \
        update
```

***Update :
Same version and same command working on mac os. But not working on amazon linux 2.
Using same openjdk 8 version

Answer (score 0):

While checking liquibase code base I realise that there is a **bug** in liquibase.
I have raised the issue here is the link :
https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/2674

Also raised PR to fix it :
https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/pull/2675

If anyone want to use one can build it locally and use.